# Change input value based on select input

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following script should do:

When a value is entered in the input, the outcome (in an other div) should be multiplied with a number. This number changes, when other `select` `option` is chosen.

#### Code

```
$('#dePlooi').change(function(){
 if ($("#dePlooi").val() == "2") {
   $("#txt_name").on("keyup change", function() {
   var value = this.value;
   var valuemath = value * 2.5;  
    $("#dom_element").text(valuemath);   
});
 } 
 else if ($("#dePlooi").val() == "3") {
   $("#txt_name").on("keyup change", function() {
   var value = this.value;
   var valuemath = value * 3;  
   $("#dom_element").text(valuemath);    
   });
 } else if ($("#dePlooi").val() == "1") {
     $("#txt_name").on("keyup change", function() {
   var value = this.value;
   var valuemath = value * 2;  
   $("#dom_element").text(valuemath);    
   });
 }
});
```

This works a little, but only if a select option is chosen and then the input is changed. I want it to happen this way but ALSO it needs to change the input on select option change. So for example:

How do I make it so that when the input or the select option is changed, the event fires?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/eJvMb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to simply bind two events, one for on select change and one for on keyup.

```
var multiplier = 1;

// bind keyup
 $("#txt_name").on("keyup change", function() {
   var value = this.value;
   var valuemath = value * multiplier;  
    $("#dom_element").text(valuemath);   
});

$('#dePlooi').change(function(){
    multiplier = $(this).val();
    $("#txt_name").trigger("keyup");
});
```

[Take a look at this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/DMvQ6/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var ploVal=0;
    var textVal=0;

    $('#dePlooi').change(function(){
     ploVal=this.value;
        calculate();
        //$("#dom_element").text(tot);
    });
     $("#txt_name").on("keyup change", function() {

         var textVal=this.value;

          calculate();
    });

    function calculate()
    {
        ploVal=$("#dePlooi").val();
    textVal=  $("#txt_name").val();  
          var tot=ploVal * textVal;
        $("#dom_element").text(tot);
        //alert($("#dePlooi").val());
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on event for this

```
 $(document).on("change","#dePlooi,#txt_name",function(){
    var value = $("#txt_name").val(),
    valuemath = value *  $("#dePlooi").val();  
    $("#dom_element").text(valuemath); 
 });
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJvMb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don`t You try this simple code:

```
<input type="text" id="txt_name"  class="testclass" />

<select id="dePlooi" name="dePlooi" class="testclass">
    <option value="0">Choose</option>
     <option value="1">x2</option>
     <option value="2">x2.5</option>
    <option value="3">x3</option>
</select>

<div id="dom_element">-</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.testclass').change(function(){
    if($('#dePlooi').val()=="0" ||$.trim($('#txt_name').val())==""){
        $('#dom_element').html("");
    }else{
        var valueToFill=parseInt($('#dePlooi').val())*parseInt($.trim($('#txt_name').val()));
        $('#dom_element').html(valueToFill);    
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95ryq/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to bind the `keyup` event every time when the drop-down options is changed.

You can achieve your goals, simply binding the  `keyup` and `change` separately.

Try this:

```
// Bind "keyup" event on textbox
    $("#txt_name").on("keyup change", function() {      
       var value = this.value;
        var valuemath = 0;
        if($('#dePlooi').val() > 0){    
          value = value * parseFloat($("#dePlooi option:selected").text().replace("x",""));  
        }
        $("#dom_element").text(valuemath);   
    });

// Bind "change" event on textbox
    $('#dePlooi').change(function(){   
        if($("#txt_name").val().trim() != ""){
            var value = $("#txt_name").val().trim();
            var valuemath = 0;
            if($(this).val() > 0){ 
              value = value * parseFloat($("#dePlooi option:selected").text().replace("x",""));  
            }
            $("#dom_element").text(valuemath);
        }
    });
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eJvMb/6/)